# What is the equivalent of the "amount of fuel" for a battery?

Tags: energy, electric-current, voltage, power, batteries

I am trying to make a performance diagram of an electrical powered device vs range, speed, etc. I want to compare it using the equivalent of fuel for a battery? I am not sure if it is just voltage... is there any other measure?

Comment: You mean battery capacity? That's measured in different ways. The easiest measurement is in Ah (Ampere-hours), which basically says how much current one can draw for a given length of time. Say a battery has 12Ah capacity, then one could draw, at most, 1A for 12h or 0.1A for 120h. In practice this capacity will decrease with increasing current. If we also know the battery voltage (which will decline as we discharge the battery), then we can multiply the voltage and the current and integrate to get the total amount of energy that we can draw out of the battery, measured in Joule.

Comment: Do you mean a fuel cell which directly converts fuel (eg: methane or ethanol) to electricity? Or are you talking about using a 'fuel' to recharge a more 'conventional' secondary battery such as a lead-acid or NiMH (such as in the GM-Volt electric vehicle)?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare chemical energy stored in the battery versus chemical energy in hydrocarbon fuels or hydrogen/oxygen engine or heat engines. Hydrocarbon engines get to use atmospheric oxygen "for free".

Watt-hours or Killowatt-hours. Instantaneous V x I summed over reasonable intervals to get power over time, or watt-hours. This is for DC - no funny phase angles.

Then look at the efficiencies with which useable energies are produced. You might think for instance that since electricity can be used to make heat with 100 percent efficiency, a battery would do well at this. But the internal resistance of the battery has to be taken into account and the result is not as pretty. With LEDs the conversion to light is very good compared to using heat to make something incandescent or a carbon arc light (which depends on nitrogen in the atmosphere and produces enough UV to give everyone sun burns, but makes a hell of a lot of light).

You can start with just Killo-Joules available per Kg. I think liquid fuels will be impressive here even if you include atmospheric oxygen.

You can calculate kJoules from horse power for motors - 746 Watts is 1 HP or 746 joules per second. Some new European cars actually use the French Metric in places and describe power in Killowatts. What with various inefficiencies, for cars it is pretty close to just figure 1000kW per horse power. It is easier to compare performance like time for 1/4 mile. My Ford GT plain Jane model is 550 hp or 410 kW and 3.3 seconds 0 to 60.

You can make a power measuring tool using simple processor like an Arduno Uno and its built in ADC. A calibrated "shunt" with a max of 10 Amps or so (lots on eBay and low cost. Everybody needs on in the lab bench). Use one ADC to measure voltage drop across the shunt (with a simple op-amp to get full scale at your typical highest current) and the other ADC to measure voltage between the battery terminal and ground. Put that battery under load and multiply the two values ten times a second and add them up. Divide by ten when done to get Watt-seconds.

For an alkaline or lead-acid battery decide where you want to quit. For a Lithium-ion, the proper batteries have circuits to prevent over charging and over-discharging and quit when it flattens out or quit when it reaches safe discharge voltage.

For fuel, search for some values for energy content of octane, which is the average in a lot of auto fuel.

There is a lot of info on JP4 because of civilian and Military use in jet engines. It is about half gasoline and half kerosene so you can think of it as octane and dodecane (C8H18 and C12H26). Stoichiometry for these hydrocarbons in oxygen is simple and you can even calculate energy from scratch, but there is tons of good reference material. Hope that helps.